# Agda: Confusion with Inspect

Tags: agda

Given the following snippet

```
open import Data.Bool
open import Data.Unit
open import Function using (id)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

what? : Bool → ⊤
what? true with id true | inspect id true
... | true  | [  true≡true  ] = {!!}
... | false | [ false≡false ] = {!!} -- why?
what? false = tt
```

why does Agda provide evidence of `false ≡ false` in the second hole when we are pattern matching on `inspect id true` which is of type `Reveal id · true is true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `inspect id true` is `Reveal id · true is id true`, which reduces to `Reveal id · true is true` as you said. However I think what's happening is `id true` gets generalized and rewritten instead of being reduced. For example, in the following case

```
wwhat? : ⊤
wwhat? with true
... | true  = {!!}
... | false = {!!}
```

Agda [generalizes](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2.2.20221128/language/with-abstraction.html#generalisation) `true` to a new variable of type `Bool`, at which point it no longer knows that the value of this variable has to be `true`, hence Agda requires us to handle both the `true` and `false` cases in the pattern match.

Therefore, in

```
what? : Bool → ⊤
what? true with id true | inspect id true
... | true  | [  true≡true  ] = {!!}
... | false | [ false≡false ] = {!!} -- why?
what? false = tt
```

`id true` is generalized to a variable, which later gets matched against `false`, resulting in `id true` being rewritten to `false` in every type in the context, including the type `inspect id true`, which becomes `Reveal id · false is false`, which being matched against `[ false≡false ]` introduces `false≡false : false ≡ false` into the scope.

---

If you want to abstract over some value, but remember that the new variable equals this value you can use the now deprecated version of the `inspect` idiom:

```
data OldInspect {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) : Set a where
  _with-≡_ : (y : A) (eq : x ≡ y) → OldInspect x

oldInspect : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) → OldInspect x
oldInspect x = x with-≡ refl

wwwhat? : ⊤
wwwhat? with oldInspect true
... | true  with-≡ refl = tt
... | false with-≡ ()
```

In the last line we refute the proof coming after `with-≡`, since it's of type `true ≡ false` and is therefore uninhabited.

Comment: Hi effectfully, thank you for the convincing answer. I still wonder if there is a way to carry over the knowledge that the argument has a certain value (here: `true`) into the with-clauses, potentially using `inspect`. In some use cases using `inspect` seems to do exactly that but here the with-statement generalizes the parameter as well as the inspect value.

Comment: @PaulProgrammerNoob I've updated the answer. Basically the current `inspect` idiom works well for applied functions and the old `inspect` idiom works for pure values when there are no function applications.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example and the explanation! :) This helps a lot.